# How to clear :hover styles for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

Here is my codepen: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/mbowen/pen/LpbbQw)

```
    .sidebar{
      width: 100%;
      position: static;
      display: block;
      padding: 50px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 562px;
      border: none;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 5%;

     }
```

I set a media query to change the styles of the page when under 700px. I want all of the :hover styles to go away on the top navigation, but I cannot get them to go away.

Also, I'm having a problem with the .sidebar element and the fixed footer overlapping at the bottom. I added margin to the bottom of the body and that didn't fix it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why not only add the :hover only  _over_ a certain screen width?

Comment: I would suggest developing using a mobile first approach - This way you can define the styles for screens lower than 700px first (omitting hover styles), then using media queries, add the hover states to items when the screen is greater than 700px

Answer (score 0):

Just put the :hover rules into queries like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjNRam

```
@media  (min-width: 700px){
  nav ul li:hover{
     background: #e92121;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is  add the:

nav ul li:hover

inside the media query. 
The selector is a bit too specific, you should avoid it or you're going to have problem in override stuff later in the project. As well try to use class.